# Creating a filled curve from scratch

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am trying to build a patch to create rectangle curve similarly to circle curve, I am likely not understanding something foundational about filled curve since creating a series of connected lines and connecting geometry does not seem to be enough - placing *Fill Curve* node along the way make geometry disappear altogether.

My higher level question here is what's the canonical way to create a closed curve that can be filled?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fundamental fact you are missing is that the *Join Geometry* is not a "weld geometry" node.

*Join Geometry* gathers different elements from a node tree into a single output, but it doesn't alter geometry in any way. It won't "merge" meshes or curves, nor will it join separate peaces by welding nearby vertex into a single continuous shape that can be filled.

Sadly there isn't one in Blender at the time of writing, as far as I know, so you can't really merger different curve splines or pieces of mesh segments into a single continuous chunk of connected geometry at the moment using geometry nodes alone.

As such your result cannot be filled since it is not a closed shape made from a single continuous spline, so it fails to create a surface.

In terms of workflow I think you are also overcomplicating. There is a *Curve Quadrilateral* node under curve primitives which yields a closed quadrilateral that can be filled by default.

As a workaround, if converting to mesh as an intermediate step in a viable option, you can create your curve segments as geometry nodes as you already did, and convert to a mesh at the end. After the *Geometry Nodes* modifier you can add a *Weld* modifier which will effectively merge nearby vertex and weld them into a single continuous geometry. After that you can add another *Geometry Nodes* for further processing, which among other operations can start by converting the resulting mesh back into a curve.

[image]

Comment: Ah great, spot on Quadrilateral sounds exactly like what I’m looking for right now, but I was thinking about extending it further. Good to know it’s not currently possible. 
As far as I understand it’s not possible to create a new patch (like in Sverchok wiring python code) unless opening a pull request, right?

Comment: You might be able to create one as a mesh instead though, use a weld modifier afterwards and do any further processing as a separate geometry node

Answer (score 2):

There's a Quadrilateral curve primitive that works with Fill Curve. It's present in 3.1 Alpha (not sure about 3.0).

Comment: It's there in 3.0, too.

Answer (score 2):

you could do it "in a way" manually by this node setup:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As another workaround you can also go via *Merge by Distance*. So *Curve to Mesh* into *Merge by Distance* into *Mesh to Curve* into *Fill Curve* like

[image: Curve to Mesh into Merge by Distance into Mesh to Curve into Fill Curve]