# Geometry Nodes: Array on a curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I have a tunnel 'section' that I would like to array on a curve using Geometry Nodes.
I think the order I am doing things in GN is wrong as I can't get the object to join/weld to the next section and create one mesh.

Trying to create a mineshaft and was thinking I should try and use geometry nodes to be able to make the path procedural so it is easy to change.
I am a noob to GN and not sure how to approch this (and couldn't find anything online).

I can easily do it using the modifiers but cannot wrap my head around how doing it using GN.

something like this also, attaching .blend file.
thanks for all the help.

[image]

https://pasteall.org/media/e/1/e1677d0a2e03b3f8f3d16e4c4b680ca5.blend

Comment: Same problem as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248695/creating-a-filled-curve-from-scratch/248731#248731 ?

Comment: The easiest way is to add an array modifier and a curve modifier to your tunnel segment; I have no idea how to do this with Geometry Nodes.[![Modifier setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IryGu.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IryGu.png)

Comment: I know, Thanks.
I think we might have to wait for more nodes to show up

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/35559

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at this one "**Curve De-former Using Blender Geometry Nodes**"

https://youtu.be/sNpWs1xbNOU?t=581

Or another way:

[image: img1]

Comment: That is perfect! Just so very complicated, blender must create a core node for deformation

Comment: True, I'm sure they're working on it, the issue for them is which one of the multiple nodes should they work on / add first.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following node setup?
[image]

You may want to make your tunnel segment shorter, so it fits corners better, but the idea is there. Then, you can also change the 'count' parameter in the 'Curve to Points' node to 'length', to fit the length of the curve automatically.

Comment: After testing this is not quite the right way to go, the mesh does not curve with the mesh what makes it impossible to weld the verts.
https://ibb.co/BzqfbW4